# Reserve contiguous space in memory with NSMutableData

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsdata, nsmutabledata, memory-layout

How can I force `NSMutableData` to reserve contiguous memory, in the same section? I have a fair amout of data arriving piece by piece, and the performance is not satisfactory. The total size of my data will be constant.

Comment: Create the `NSMutableData` object with either `dataWithCapacity:` or `initWithCapacity:`.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, I will use initWithCapacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSMutableData` should store all data contiguously. Internally it is using a "stretchy" buffer resized with realloc. You can create with `[NSMutableData dataWithLength:];`

Why not use an `NSData` if the size is constant?

Also why are you worrying about `NSMutableData` performance. Did instruments profile show a performance problem?

Comment: Hi @Justin, Ok I´ll explain a little more, the buffer size is constant but I write to this by parts, the data comes from an external accessory so each time I receive data I need to copy it into the rigth position. I´m worry about performance since I receive 64KB of information from the accessory and it is taking 3+ seconds (for me it is a lot) so I´m trying to optimize the code.

Comment: @JoseAlbertoDiaz write into the data using memcpy([data mutableBytes] + offset, source, size); or maybe the more cocoa friendly replaceBytesInRange:withBytes: